# How to hide the markdown while converting a notebook to html format

Tags: python, jupyter

I have written a code to display few plots related to my project and I have to convert it to html form for better visualization. I have managed to remove the lines of code using the following piece of code

```
os.system('jupyter nbconvert plots.ipynb --to html --no-input ')
```

The lines of code have gone but not the markdowns . Is there any command to remove them as well and display only the plots which I have got. I don't want to remove the markdowns from original code as I need it for the explanation of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TemplateExporter.exclude_markdown` ([exporter options](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/5.6.1/config_options.html#exporter-options)). Then your command will be:

```bash
jupyter nbconvert plots.ipynb --to html --no-input --TemplateExporter.exclude_markdown=True
```